# ArrayList TextInput Equals Condition Not Showing What The User Entered

Tags: java, android, arraylist

So I have 3 objects in my array that I fetched from API, in my case when the user input some text and the value of text input will be compared with the promo name (bottom row of the picture below) it will show the promo name on the screen. But when I entered the text, it'll show the second position (HELLO) only, how can I solve this when I enter the text like PROMOBERKAH it will show PROMOBERKAH, when I enter JULICERIA it will show JULICERIA? Thanks.

[image]

Here's my conditional code,

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                for (int i=0;i<ar1.size();i++) {
                    if (ar1.contains(edtVoucherCode.getText().toString())) {
                        int position = ar1.indexOf(edtVoucherCode.getText().toString());
                        codeNotFound.setText("Kode promo berhasil digunakan");
                        codeNotFound.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1ECBB5"));
                        codeNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isValid = true;
                        usePromoPrivateId = jsonData.get(position).getId_promo();
                        usePromoPrivateName = jsonData.get(position).getPromo_name();
                        if (jsonData.get(position).getPromo_type().equals("1")) {
                            usePromoPrivateDiscount = jsonData.get(position).getValue_based();;
                        } else {
                            usePromoPrivateDiscountPrice = jsonData.get(position).getValue_based();;
                        }
                    } else {
                        codeNotFound.setText("Kode promo tidak ditemukan");
                        codeNotFound.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#DF2C2E"));
                        codeNotFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding indexOf to my conditional code

```
int position = ar1.indexOf(edtVoucherCode.getText().toString());
```